# snapshot.getChildren() prints the values while getValue() returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble with snapshot being able to print the values, but being specific by using get values returns null.

I'm trying to retrieve the the list uploaded in Firebase and compare it to the list that the user will pass.

```
 rootReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot item_child : snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String recId = item_child.getKey();
                DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://what-s-cookin-a3bec-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/")
                        .getReference().child("Recipes").child(recId);

                Log.d(TAG, "RECID: " + recId);
                rootReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, "SNAPSHOT: " + ds);
                            Log.d(TAG, "SPECIFIC: " + ds.child("ingredients"));
                            if(ds.child("ingredients").getValue() != null)
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "INGREDIENTS NOT NULL");
                                ArrayList<String> ing = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (DataSnapshot ings : snapshot.child("ingredients").getChildren())
                                {
                                    ing.add(ings.getValue(String.class));
                                    Log.d(TAG, "DS: " + ds);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "INGS: " + ings);
                                }
```

This is the result from logcat:

```
SNAPSHOT: DataSnapshot { key = ingredients, value = {0=Fish, 1=bitter, 2=cilantro} }
SPECIFIC: DataSnapshot { key = ingredients, value = null }
```

[Logcat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va9nk.jpg)

This is our firebase:
[Firebase Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNtkG.jpg)

Recipes
1634971267099
favCount:  8
id:  "1634971267099"
imageUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wha..."
ingredients
0: "Fish"
1: "bitter"
2: "cilantro"
mainIng:  "Pork"
measure:  "test"
name:  "Pochero"
prod:  "test"
serve:  "15"
time:  "30"
uid:  "tMdUFcAelyeVo5DYW3P7HolRW4S2"

Comment: Your second `for` loops over `snapshot.child("ingredients").getChildren()`, but that should be `ds.child("ingredients").getChildren()`. I highly recommend using meaningful variable names to prevent such mistakes.

Comment: Thank you but that wasn't the problem. I changed the variables to what you suggested but it still gives the same problem. When I use getChildren(), it prints out everything the database has but when I call it specifically child.("ingredients").getValue(), it returns null

Comment: This was definitely one of the problems in your code. You're first checking `if(ds.child("ingredients").getValue()` and then loop with `for (DataSnapshot ings : snapshot.child("ingredients").getChildren())`, so you're using the `ingredients` child of the wrong snapshot in one of those. If you fixed that and still have the same problem, edit your question to show the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code is matching with Firebase data.
It would be more clear if you post screenshot of Firebase data to understand the database hierarchy.

Its difficult to understand the database structure from your code.

Comment: I edited the question and added the firebase hierarchy. Sorry about that